# Display feature count in legend by map extent using mask and atlas plugins in print composer

Tags: print-composer, feature-count

I'm trying to generate thematic maps from point layers representing citizen requests using QGIS's Atlas map composer plugin as well as the Mask plugin to target the number of requests per district.

I would like to have the count of requests by district in order to display it in my legend. Unfortunately, this returns the wrong value. I used the expression below in the map composer.

```
aggregate( 
layer:='DebrisVoiePlubliqueFinale',
aggregate:='count',
expression:=$id,
filter:=intersects(
            $geometry,
            map_get(item_variables('DebrisVoiePublique'), 'map_extent')    
        )
```

)

See screenshot below. The true value for this rounding is **54 requests**.

Any idea why this is not working?

Best regards,

[image: Map canvas]
[image: Map Composer]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution to my problem. It was simply a matter of adding the `@atlas_geometry` function which allows intersecting the point layer with that of the polygon.

The expression has been simplified from the previous one:

```
aggregate(
  layer:= 'Point feature layer',
  aggregate:='count',
  expression:=$id,
  filter:=intersects($geometry, @atlas_geometry)
)
```